# Append style for matrix of nodes in a loop doesn't work

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

Following this question [defining-nodes-of-a-matrix-programmatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437267/defining-nodes-of-a-matrix-programmatically/), I was able to precise more of what I am trying to achieve. Sorry that I was way too general in the first question.
Here is the new MWE. Reading the first question ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437267/defining-nodes-of-a-matrix-programmatically/)) is absolutely essential.

My end goal is to define node positioning in a matrix, the nodes are not placed at the same distance of each others.

I am able to define the dimensions of each node with append style with method 1, but would like to achieve it with method 2 or 3 (or a similar method). For some reason, looping is not working properly for appending to style : maybe I need to buffer the information somewhere ?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{dimensionsBigBox/.style={
        minimum height=3cm,
        rectangle, 
        fill=none, draw=blue,
        text depth=0.5em, text height=1em,
}}

\tikzset{dimensionsSmallBox/.style={
        minimum height=1cm,
        rectangle, 
        fill=none, draw=red,
        text depth=0.5em, text height=1em,
}}

\tikzset{
mygridmatrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes, 
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    nodes={draw}, 
    nodes in empty cells,
},
}


\iftrue
    % Method 1 : Block of hardcoded definition of the nodes
    \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={dimensionsSmallBox}}}}
    \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 1 column 2/.style={nodes={dimensionsSmallBox}}}}
    \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 1 column 3/.style={nodes={dimensionsSmallBox}}}}
    \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 2 column 1/.style={nodes={dimensionsBigBox}}}}
    \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 2 column 2/.style={nodes={dimensionsBigBox}}}}
    \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 2 column 3/.style={nodes={dimensionsBigBox}}}}
    \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 3 column 1/.style={nodes={dimensionsSmallBox}}}}
    \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 3 column 2/.style={nodes={dimensionsSmallBox}}}}
    \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 3 column 3/.style={nodes={dimensionsSmallBox}}}}
\fi

\iffalse
    % Method 2 : Append style and loop with xintFor ==> only apply the last style of the loop iteration
    %\xintForpair #1#2 in  {(1,dimensionsBigBox), (2,dimensionsSmallBox), (3,dimensionsBigBox),(4,dimensionsSmallBox), (5,dimensionsSmallBox), (6,dimensionsSmallBox), (7,dimensionsBigBox), (8,dimensionsBigBox), (9,dimensionsBigBox), (2,dimensionsSmallBox)} \do {
    \xintForpair #1#2 in  {(1,dimensionsBigBox), (2,dimensionsSmallBox), (3,dimensionsBigBox),(4,dimensionsSmallBox), (5,dimensionsSmallBox), (6,dimensionsSmallBox), (7,dimensionsBigBox), (8,dimensionsBigBox), (9,dimensionsBigBox)} \do {
        %Set style #2 for node  #1 \\
        \pgfmathsetmacro\row{int(div(#1-1,3)+1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\col{int(mod(#1-1,3)+1)}
        \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row \row\space column \col/.style={nodes={#2}}}}
        }
\fi



\iffalse
    % Method 3 : Append style and loop with foreach ==> doesn't apply any style
    \foreach \x/\y  in  {1/dimensionsBigBox, 2/dimensionsBigBox, 3/dimensionsBigBox, 4/dimensionsSmallBox, 5/dimensionsSmallBox, 6/dimensionsSmallBox, 7/dimensionsBigBox, 8/dimensionsBigBox, 9/dimensionsBigBox}{
        %Set style \y for node  \x \\
        \pgfmathsetmacro\row{int(div(\x-1,3)+1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\col{int(mod(\x-1,3)+1)}
        \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row \row\space column \col/.style={nodes={\y}}}}
    }
\fi

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [mygridmatrix]
    {
        1&2&3\\
        4&5&6\\
        7&8&9\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: you set nine time the same style! in your mwe it will only take into account the last definition :-).

Comment: It is obvious why method 3 is not working, this is why we need normally `\xintFor`. But for me it is not clear at all why method 2 is not working :( If you are interested in a workaround you can store your style in a variable, for example with `\edef\temp{\temp,row \row\space column \col/.style={#2}}`, and then use it to append the style to `mygridmatrix` with `\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append code={\expandafter\expandafter\pgfkeysalso{\temp}}}` ... but this is ugly :(

Comment: Fantastic, it's working !!!
I will redact the final code tomorrow in case someone is interested.
Or do you want to redact it, for the point stuff ?

Comment: in method 2, ``\edef\zzz{\noexpand\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row \row\space column \col/.style={nodes={#2}}}}}\zzz`` works (sort of, because therer seems to be confusion in the pairs between small and big boxes). It seems `\tikzset` does not expand `\row` and `\col` when parsing its input, hence the last iteration of the loop give them the only used values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For method 2, as suggested by @jfbu in his comment, you need to force the expansion of `row \row\space column \col` and for this you can simply add `/.expanded`, like this :

```
% Method 2 : Append style and loop with xintFor
\xintForpair #1#2 in {(1,dimensionsBigBox), (2,dimensionsSmallBox), (3,dimensionsBigBox),(4,dimensionsSmallBox), (5,dimensionsSmallBox), (6,dimensionsSmallBox), (7,dimensionsBigBox), (8,dimensionsBigBox), (9,dimensionsBigBox)} \do {
  %Set style #2 for node  #1 \\
  \pgfmathsetmacro\row{int(div(#1-1,3)+1)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\col{int(mod(#1-1,3)+1)}
  \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style/.expanded={row \row\space column \col/.style={nodes={#2}}}}
}
```

To use `foreach` loop like in method 3 you can save the style in a temp variable and set it outside the loop, like this:

```
% Method 3 : Append style and loop with foreach
\xdef\temp{}
\foreach[count=\x from 0] \y in {dimensionsBigBox,dimensionsBigBox,dimensionsBigBox,dimensionsSmallBox,dimensionsSmallBox,dimensionsSmallBox,dimensionsBigBox,dimensionsBigBox,dimensionsBigBox}{
  %Set style \y for node  \x 
  \pgfmathsetmacro\row{int(div(\x,3)+1)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\col{int(mod(\x,3)+1)}
  \xdef\temp{\temp,row \row\space column \col/.style={\y}}
}
\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style/.expanded={\temp}}
```

And here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  dimensionsBigBox/.style={
    minimum height=3cm,
    rectangle,
    fill=none, draw=blue,
    text depth=0.5em, text height=1em,
  },
  dimensionsSmallBox/.style={
    minimum height=1cm,
    rectangle,
    fill=none, draw=red,
    text depth=0.5em, text height=1em,
  },
  mygridmatrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw},
    nodes in empty cells,
  }
}


% Method 1 : Block of hardcoded definition of the nodes
\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={dimensionsBigBox}}}}
\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 1 column 2/.style={nodes={dimensionsBigBox}}}}
\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 1 column 3/.style={nodes={dimensionsBigBox}}}}
\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 2 column 1/.style={nodes={dimensionsSmallBox}}}}
\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 2 column 2/.style={nodes={dimensionsSmallBox}}}}
\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 2 column 3/.style={nodes={dimensionsSmallBox}}}}
\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 3 column 1/.style={nodes={dimensionsBigBox}}}}
\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 3 column 2/.style={nodes={dimensionsBigBox}}}}
\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style={row 3 column 3/.style={nodes={dimensionsBigBox}}}}

\tikz\matrix (m) [mygridmatrix,label=above:Method 1 (hardcoded)] {1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\\};


% Method 2 : Append style and loop with xintFor
\xintForpair #1#2 in {(1,dimensionsBigBox), (2,dimensionsBigBox), (3,dimensionsBigBox),(4,dimensionsSmallBox), (5,dimensionsSmallBox), (6,dimensionsSmallBox), (7,dimensionsBigBox), (8,dimensionsBigBox), (9,dimensionsBigBox)} \do {
    %Set style #2 for node  #1
  \pgfmathsetmacro\row{int(div(#1-1,3)+1)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\col{int(mod(#1-1,3)+1)}
  \tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style/.expanded={row \row\space column \col/.style={nodes={#2}}}}
}

\tikz\matrix (m) [mygridmatrix,label=above:Method 2 (using xintFor)] {1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\\};

% Method 3 : Append style and loop with foreach
\xdef\temp{}
\foreach[count=\x from 0] \y in {dimensionsBigBox,dimensionsBigBox,dimensionsBigBox,dimensionsSmallBox,dimensionsSmallBox,dimensionsSmallBox,dimensionsBigBox,dimensionsBigBox,dimensionsBigBox}{
  %Set style \y for node  \x
  \pgfmathsetmacro\row{int(div(\x,3)+1)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\col{int(mod(\x,3)+1)}
  \xdef\temp{\temp,row \row\space column \col/.style={\y}}
}
\tikzset{mygridmatrix/.append style/.expanded={\temp}}

\tikz\matrix (m) [mygridmatrix,label=above:Method 3 (using foreach)] {1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\\};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a long conversation. ;-) Here is another attempt. You just need to run the `\xintForpair` with a new list and will get a different matrix.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{dimensionsBigBox/.style={
        minimum height=3cm,
        rectangle, 
        fill=none, draw=blue,
        text depth=0.5em, text height=1em,
}}

\tikzset{dimensionsSmallBox/.style={
        minimum height=1cm,
        rectangle, 
        fill=none, draw=red,
        text depth=0.5em, text height=1em,
}}

\tikzset{
mygridmatrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes, 
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
    nodes={draw}, 
    nodes in empty cells,
},
}
   \xintForpair #1#2 in  {(1,dimensionsBigBox), (2,dimensionsSmallBox), (3,dimensionsBigBox),(4,dimensionsSmallBox), (5,dimensionsSmallBox), (6,dimensionsSmallBox), (7,dimensionsBigBox), (8,dimensionsBigBox), (9,dimensionsBigBox)} \do {
        %Set style #2 for node  #1 \\
        \pgfmathsetmacro\row{int(div(#1-1,3)+1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\col{int(mod(#1-1,3)+1)}
        \tikzset{mygridmatrix-\row-\col/.style={#2}}
        }

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={minimum width=6mm}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes] (m) {%
|[mygridmatrix-1-1,alias=topleft]|& |[mygridmatrix-1-2]| &|[mygridmatrix-1-3]|\\ 
|[mygridmatrix-2-1]|& |[mygridmatrix-2-2]| &|[mygridmatrix-2-3]|\\ 
|[mygridmatrix-3-3]|& |[mygridmatrix-3-2]| &|[mygridmatrix-3-3,alias=bottomright]|\\ };
\draw[blue,-latex] (topleft.center) -- (bottomright.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```